# Como usar o SimpleInjector em um projeto multi-camada?

Tags: c#, arquitetura-de-software, injeção-de-dependência, ioc, simple-injector

Imagine a clássica arquitetura:

ConsoleApplication (Frontend) --> Camada de Negócios (BLL) --> Camada de Acesso à Dados (DAL)

Ou seja, Frontend referencia BLL que referencia DAL. Veja que o Frontend não conheçe a DAL, e nem deve.

Dado que o o registro do meu container deve ser no Entry Point da aplicação (FrontEnd) como eu posso registrar uma dependência de um repositório da camada DAL se o Frontend não conheçe a DAL?

Imagine a seguinte estrutura:

**DAL**

```
// Camada DAL
public class DAOPessoa : IDAOPessoa
{
    public DAOPessoa()
    {

    }

    public List<string> Obter()
    {
        return new List<string>() { "Pessoa 1", "Pessoa 2", "Pessoa 3" };
    }
}
```

**BLL**

```
// CAMADA BLL
public class Processador
{
    private readonly IDAOPessoa _daoPessoa;

    public Processador(IDAOPessoa daoPessoa)
    {
        this._daoPessoa = daoPessoa;
    }

    public void Processar()
    {
        this._daoPessoa.Obter();
    }
}
```

**FRONTEND**

```
//Um console application, por exemplo
public static class Program
{
    static readonly Container container;

    static Program()
    {
        // 1. Create a new Simple Injector container
        container = new Container();

        // 2. Configure the container (register)
        container.Register<IDAOPessoa, DAOPessoa>(); // Aqui fica sublinhado em vermelhor pois este assembly (Frontend) não conheçe nada da DAL


        // 3. Verify your configuration
        container.Verify();
    }
}
```

Existe algum padrão ou recomendação para resolver este problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, você deve criar seu IoC como um CrossCutting. Ou seja, um projeto, DLL, que possuem cache dos registros, e que enxerga todos os projetos.

Você pode ver um exemplo aqui: https://github.com/thiagolunardi/EquinoxProject/blob/master/src/Equinox.Infra.CrossCutting.IoC/NativeInjectorBootStrapper.cs

Basta, então, adicionar o projeto de IoC no seu frontend e solicitar o registro no container.

No final, vc tem seu container de injeção de dependência com todos os registros necessários, seu frontend sem enxergar seu DAL

Comment: Hum boa abordagem também, pelo que entendi então cria-se uma class library responsável pelo IOC referenciando todo mundo que for necessário? e o "FrontEnd" dele chama essa DLL e ela faz o trabalho?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Assim vc tem um projeto de responsabilidade única.

Comment: Muito bom... Desde o início imaginei que essa seria a solução ideal, fiz a pergunta só pra confirmar e também porque vi vários post defendendo que o próprio frontend poderia referenciar tudo, nestes posts as pessoas argumentavam que referenciar a DLL de DAL, por exemplo, não necessariamente cria dependência entre os objetos, isso é verdade, mas é perigoso. A solução que vc sugere é muito mais elegante e segura.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do Lunardi, e olhando de outra perspectiva:

- Criar um projeto de Infraestrutura e relacionar as dependências (esse é o ponto de "wiring" do seu DI);
- Criar um projeto Core , possui os DTOs e extensões, e Contratos.
- Criar seu console app (Frontend) e referenciar ao Infra e Core.
- Criar seu BLL dependendo apenas do Core.
- Criar seu DAL dependendo apenas do Core.